# Calling a SOAP 1.1 Service from WCF

Tags: wcf, soap, fiddler

I am trying to call a SOAP 1.1 Service using https from a WCF Service. I have the wsdl url, and having downloaded the service client, I tried to use the service client but I got the following exception:

An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://iviewv2qa.regulusgroup.com/dis-t2/services/dis.wsdl. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

The really strange part is, when I have fiddler open, this exception is not generated, and I can consume the service just fine. But when I close fiddler, I get this exception.

Could it have something to do with the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because of the proxy settings, and the specifying the details of the proxy in the configuration will solve the issue.

```
 <system.net>
<defaultProxy>
  <proxy proxyaddress="Your Proxy Address"/>
</defaultProxy>
```